# does postgresql cost model respect plan cost monotonicity

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

**Plan Cost Monotonicity(PCM)**:
This assumption says as estimated selectivity of a query by the optimizer increases the cost calculated by Optimizer in abstract units also increases.

**Selectivity**: Fraction of tuples that are going to be in the result set.

Say I have 
Query 1:

```
select * from lineitem where l_extendedprice < 5000;
```

Query2:

```
select * from lineitem where l_extendedprice < 10000;
```

The cost calculated for Query1 should be less than cost calculated for Query2 if PCM assumption holds since selectivity of Query2 is higher than Query1.

Does this always hold in **PostgreSQL** irrespective of the complexity of the query?

Can we assume Plan cost monotonicity practically?

Is there any relationship between **cost vs query execution times**?

Comment: Note: "cost" is not a 1-dimentional thing. There is buffer cost, memory cost, I/O cost, CPU cost, planning cost, ...  And of course the resulting overall query time.

Comment: @wildplasser By "cost" I meant the cost in abstract units that gets printed when you do explain query in PostgreSQL

Comment: The cost contains both estimated "time" and estimated number of rows. (plus: buffer usage and cache hits/misses, if you ask for it) And these estimates are based on the *chosen* plan. In your example: x<5000 case *may* yield a different plan than the x<10000 case; with different estimates.

Comment: Seq Scan on lineitem (cost=0.00..458.00 rows=10000 width=244). I am talking about the cost 458 here. I know that it is computed based on various factors by the optimizer. But I have observed that to an extent when selectivity increases for the same query with different constants cost increases as well. You can assume even that plans are same.

Comment: The 458 could be considered a measure of time; but not as absolute value in seconds. The way it is calculated depends on the selectivity, and the coverage of the available statistics. And there are some switch-mode points in the calculation of the selectivity. Check the source! Note these estimates are **not** intended to forecast the running time of the query, only to compare candidate plans, and select the *most probably* best plan.

Comment: ... and sice there are different ways to compute estimates, and these estimates are not exact (Duh!), monotonicty cannot be guaranteed. (IIUC, I'd expect a certain amount of hysteresis to be beneficial)